# Is it possible to trigger a click on a button using clientX and clientY on a window scope using vanilla js

Tags: javascript

With the follow data given to me:

```
[{"y":69,"x":63,"type":"mousedown","time":1534261731696},{"y":69,"x":63,"type":"mouseup","time":1534261731886,"data":{}}]
```

How can I trigger a click event with given clientX and clientY location there exists a button and it has a onclick handler attached.
I know I can get the find element then trigger the events but in the data that was provided to me, that was not provided.
Another option I was thinking is if there is a way to find a dom element given x and y, if exists a button then apply the events given.

This is what the dom looks at, assume that the button is located at x:63, y:69.
[image: This is where the button exists on the dom]

Here is what I have tried and didn't work:

```
//Option 1
    var clickEvent = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
          clickEvent.initMouseEvent (event.type, true, true, window, 0, event.x, event.y, event.x, event.y, false, false, false,false, 0, document.parentNode);

    window.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);

//option 2
  let mouseEvent = new Event(event.type, {
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true
      });
         mouseEvent.pageX  = event.x;
         mouseEvent.pageY = event.y;
         mouseEvent.view = window;
       window.dispatchEvent(mouseEvent)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `document.elementFromPoint(x, y).click();` where x and y are the x and y coordinates of the Element.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener("click", function(event){
   alert("Clicked");
});
document.elementFromPoint(8, 8).click();
```

```css
html, body{
 padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<button style="margin: 0;">Button</button>
```

To trigger other events, you can use this utility function:

```
function triggerEvent(el, type){
   if ('createEvent' in document) {
        // modern browsers, IE9+
        var e = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
        e.initEvent(type, false, true);
        el.dispatchEvent(e);
    } else {
        // IE 8
        var e = document.createEventObject();
        e.eventType = type;
        el.fireEvent('on'+e.eventType, e);
    }
}
```

```html
<button style="margin: 0;">Button</button>
<script>
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener("mouseup", function(event){
   alert("Mouseup");
});
var el = document.elementFromPoint(8, 8);
triggerEvent(el, 'mouseup');
function triggerEvent(el, type){
   if ('createEvent' in document) {
        var e = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
        e.initEvent(type, false, true);
        el.dispatchEvent(e);
    } else {
        var e = document.createEventObject();
        e.eventType = type;
        el.fireEvent('on'+e.eventType, e);
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: thanks, but can i use events such as mouseup and mousedown rather than click?